# Create groups of people such that no two people are on the same team.

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I have 50 people, and those 50 people are on 5 teams (10 people may not be on one team). I would like to generate 7 groups of those 50 people such that no two people in each group are on the same team.

- The groups don't have to have the same number of people.
- The groups *can* have two people who are on the same team, but it must be aggressively minimized
- The groups should all be roughly the same size

Ideally I'd like to tackle this in python but I don't particularly care about which language I implement this with.

Comment: I'm not following this.  If you have 7 or 8 people (50/7) distributed among 5 teams, then you *must* have multiple people on the same team (pigeonhole principle).  Are the groups then limited to 5 people?  Please post a smaller example to illustrate the problem space.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, and yeah now that I think about it that situation is unavoidable. I think my solution entails generating a complement graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is creating a graph of all the teams, and generating an inverse graph as such: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph